# How to Assign a popup segue to a shake motion?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, segue

I created a button that opens a popup with a segue.
and now I would like that popup to open with a "shake" motion.
for my button to open the popup (which works of course) I use

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

and for the motion (it works too) I use

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

How can I "prepareForSegue" after a shake motion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `motionEnded` implementation you can simply call `performSegueWithIdentifier`; this way `prepareForSegue` is automatically called.

Comment: just add.. segue identifier has to be set in storyboard and [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueIdentifierxxx" sender:nil] need to be called.

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you :)